# AtTask API Login Error

Tags: php, api, rest, restful-authentication, attask

I'm trying to access the AtTask API using AtTask StreamClient.php library.  I am able to login and extract information using the Chrome Advanced Rest Client, however, I am not able to login to the API from a .php script using StreamClient.  The message I keep getting is:

"Logging in...Error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to XXXXXXXXXX.attask-ondemand.com:443"

Does anyone have an idea what this means, and how to get around it.  My gut feeling is that it has something to do with the configuration of my server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: It's nothing special, or even anything that I wrote.  Just the AtTask StreamClient.php sample using my login credentials.

Comment: Here is the specific code that is failing:

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  Very strange, very strange. Apparently, you have to force CURL to use SSL Version 1.  I added the line:

```
curl_setopt($this->handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
```

to the CURL initiation part of the script and it started working.